# How to add some text in li without replacing the existing text using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently working on a list and my requirement is whenever user clicks on a radio button ,I want to append some text in the start of an li item.
I have tried using the JQuery .text() function but it replaces the existing content which I don't want to loose.

```
$("#" + condition + "-q").find("li:first").text("NOT")
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use callback function of `.text()` to modify existing value and return new value that needs to be set :

```
$("#" + condition + "-q").find("li:first").text(function(i,oldtext){
   return "NOT" + oldtext ;
})
```

Answer (score 3):

USe .append method to add text instead of replace:

```
$("#" + condition + "-q").find("li:first").append("NOT");
```

Comment: append acually creates a new li element and append it.

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla yes prepend worked.can you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

First find the current text and then add that text plus any additional text to the element.

```
var text = $("#" + condition + "-q").find("li:first").text();
$("#" + condition + "-q").find("li:first").text(text+"NOT")
```

Comment: Yes that worked too, but I was looking for a short solution and prepend solved my problem.Thanku